# Development Mura changes are reflecting in Staging and Production as well. How to stop reflcting in staging and Production?

Tags: coldfusion, content-management-system, mura

I am new to Mura. There is a website already built and from Development admin panel if I do some changes then those changes are getting reflected in Staging and Production as well.

We are using Mura 6.2.6205

How can I stop this behavior and make separate deployments for Staging and Production?

Answer (score 1):

My guess (totally a guess) is that both Staging and Production are pointing to the same DB. make a copy of the DB and make sure that staging is pointing at the *copy*. That's SOP anyway.